# What is some good open-source/freeware lightscribe-able disc labeling software for Win7?

Tags: windows-7, lightscribe

As the title says, I'm looking for some good open-source/freeware lightscribe-able on-the-disc-disc printing software. Any suggestions?

Comment: Print on the disc or print a cover for the disc?

Comment: Lightscribe implies on the disc ;).

Comment: Then why did you put "disc cover' in the title, fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one for Linux
http://qlscribe.sourceforge.net/

Linux
http://sourceforge.net/projects/qscribe/

Windows XP and earlier
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdscribe/

Comment: Dvdscribe is nice, simple, yet it tells me this (http://i.imgur.com/EkGoD.png) and this (http://i.imgur.com/tf5DF.png).

Anybody got more suggestions?

Comment: That is the problem with some open source software, they are works in progress, see the support page...http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdscribe/support

Comment: Since I just hit this “Libraries not found” issue as well: DVDScribe looks in the wrong location on x64 systems. You can use CorFlags.exe to reconfigure the application to run in x86 compatibility mode. This is also described [in this DVDScribe bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/dvdscribe/bugs/1/).